# Assign group to data frame column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi is there a way to get the output in the C column as shown in the table below using pandas built-in function
Requirement:

1. C should use the group number from B
2. If B contains different group for each group in A, then C should get the first group in B
3. if B has one same group for each group in A, then C just copy the group from B

[image]

Comment: where will A, B start ? are they fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're starting with this data:

```
    A  B
0   1  2
1   1  2
2   1  2
3   1  2
4   1  2
5   1  2
6   1  2
7   2  3
8   2  3
9   2  3
10  2  4
11  2  4
12  2  4
13  2  5
14  3  4
15  3  4
16  4  5
17  4  6
```

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) column `"A"`, [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and take the [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html) value of column `"B"` and [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) that as column `"C"`.

```py
out = df.assign(C=df.groupby("A").B.transform("first"))

print(out)
```

```
    A  B  C
0   1  2  2
1   1  2  2
2   1  2  2
3   1  2  2
4   1  2  2
5   1  2  2
6   1  2  2
7   2  3  3
8   2  3  3
9   2  3  3
10  2  4  3
11  2  4  3
12  2  4  3
13  2  5  3
14  3  4  4
15  3  4  4
16  4  5  5
17  4  6  5
```

Comment: Woah exactly as I needed. Thanks !!!